# Upgrading from QGIS 2.18 to QGIS 3.8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I have an old version of QGIS 2.4 on Laptop. I want to upgrade it to the latest version but I couldn't update it to the latest one. I tried uninstalling the old one to update it. But when I try to install it through 'sudo apt-get install' command, I ended up installing the old version again.

Comment: You didn't tell us which Ubuntu version you are using? Did you follow  qgis.org website? https://qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu and what is the output of `apt policy qgis` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the guide on the QGIS website:

Lets say you have Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) xenial.

Edit your sources by running these two commands:

`echo "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`

`echo "deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`

After that type the commands below to install QGIS:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

Comment: If you want QGIS 3.8 on Xenial, you need to use the ubuntugis ppa, see https://qgis.org/de/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id11 footnote [5].